# Typescript dynamically assign class properties

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if there was a way to assign class properties via `looping/Object.assign`, for example something like:

```
interface Foo {
    b: string
    a: string
    r: number
}

class Example implements Foo {
    constructor(ref: Foo) {
        Object.assign(this, ref)
    }
}
```

-- Edit -- Error:

> Class 'Example' incorrectly implements interface 'Foo'.   Type
> 'Example' is missing the following properties from type 'Foo': b, a, r

Comment: what is wrong with `Object.assign`?

Comment: Hi @AlirezaAhmadi I get an error saying the properties from Foo aren't implemented

Comment: I made an answer for you and put the playground link to see modified code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically assign class properties by `Object.assign`, **but** the error you have get does not relate to `Object.assign`. That is happened because you incorrectly implemented the `Foo` interface. Here is correct implementation:

interface Foo {
b: string
a: string
r: number
}

```
class Example implements Foo {
    constructor(ref: Foo) {
        Object.assign(this, ref)
    }
   b!: string;//correct implementation
   a!: string;//correct implementation
   r!: number;//correct implementation
}
```

Note that you also can have base class instead of interface like this (and **extends** the base class):

```
class BaseFoo {
    b!: string
    a!: string
    r!: number
}

class BaseExample extends BaseFoo {
    constructor(ref: Foo) {
        super();
        Object.assign(this, ref)
    }
}
```

In this case you don't repeat the properties

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIBGAXMgM5hSgDm%20hcZl1IdhyUZIArgLZHRcAX1y4EAGzjlyyAKIAPOLwAO4lMBVreEcDIxY87BOhDNuCMOigAKKBBhl9AShz12BAPJEAVhAsA6KXJgGhBrMAALYHIAGg57JzdkEUIiAEImKloAbjc4DIos1lzCKAKefmhckQB6GoBaRqbmlta29o7RCSDkACEpCH1XdnTMljYGAuZaJLKuPgEoYS7JaT6BhSVVFAh5SBAAExl%208kHMYcJjUypzSxs7BzRMF0N3AnJuZWhrJxK35C8vgCQRCYUi0TiD0S7BEQiAA)

Comment: Using a base class instead of an interface is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!