# Assign class to another class property in typescripts

Tags: typescript

I need to assign some object to class property and call this object property from this assigned class.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmEAeAwgJwKZgBcBXPAPmgG8BYAKFugegAciAjERYaYPQk3AFzQc+YngDcteo2AB7eBALYiwArOwAKHqP5CRfPAEpK0xowIALRBAB02g7mgBebrzG5JNMwF8pXxqgA1rgAyrJE8AAmGsbUdP4MvvFmojFxZmYA9JnQFrIA7tBq0EGOltbQ+eqBMIjwRQCeTLgQPIhMBKYZ5bb27jZ5+QCSBACihDFdSUm0oJAwJMBW9emMkYRgQmDwDZ5mcgpKKmqa6wSb0NsNsV1mPTZnYM7Qj3uMMwnMbBxcrYi48FwADkwMhBNBFNg6gBzZ4AIlGSzqskQkXwcK6gxG4wIMUo0z8cygEPwCBQaHQ23JIHIuAAHgQAZEYGTUBgqWzyKsGBy0FskGy3gwugdIcd1BpeSB+dTDNyMhAiM1NFLDLdzFZbFLnlL1QxskVsA1LlBEND6trij09dADQB5VgAK1wqhs8zN8A0PQANJcBWg1ckMvqcoMirISmBgkVNZVqrV6gQmi02h0bfcpQMCtiJoYhRlRbIQLgbCBZNCvZq3f6QDY-gDgaDcHmprQPsWCNAAGaIbCKEKkmvPQGFRbLDQUeBNoQAcjHdQAjDPfRBEAAvcEzhcAVmAyGXlVwZosBFnACYAAwX6Ez7wtmgdv3UhfD3CFCCD6noefwUgaHt9gQA5gKyAaeEAA)

```
class Animal<Creature> {

    public creature: Creature;

    constructor(creature: Creature) {
        this.creature = creature;
    }

    makeSound() {

    }

    eat(){
        // how to make this works in typescript
        this.creature.howItEat()
    }
}

class urchin {
    data: any;
    constructor(data: any) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public scieneName: string = "Echinoidea"
    howItEat() {}
}

class seaAnimal<animal> extends Animal<animal> {
    animal: animal;
    
    constructor(animal: animal){
        super(animal)
        this.animal = animal
        // try assign animal to this
        // Object.assign(this, animal)

        // how to make this works in typescript
        this.animal.howItEat();
        console.log(this.animal.scieneName);
    }
}

let firstSeaAnimal = new urchin({name: 'urchin1', size: '15cm', weight: '200g'});
let animal1 = new seaAnimal<urchin>(firstSeaAnimal);
```

I'm new to typescript. I tried to implement the generic type but failed. I already tried `Object.assign()` but still can't get rid the error. Got from this question [Typescript dynamically assign class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69331855/typescript-dynamically-assign-class-properties)

Comment: Given your example code, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOLRMN) is what I'd do, but this is very similar to the existing answer which is apparently insufficient.  Could you [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates enough use cases to convey why this approach doesn't work?  That would probably be more helpful than a verbal description of what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend Creature and animal generic to handle it

like this:

```
class Animal<Creature extends {howItEat:()=>any , scieneName:string}> {
...
class seaAnimal<animal extends {howItEat:()=>any,scieneName:string}> extends Animal<animal> {
```

or extend urchin

```
class Animal<Creature extends urchin> {
...
class seaAnimal<animal extends urchin> extends Animal<animal> {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=94&pln=29&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmEAeAwgJwKZgBcBXPaXADwN3gBMYBvACwHsB3ASQIFFCAuACgCUAXgB8YeAE9oAGmgRgiargByYZLl4QC2RPADmAX1HR6AWABQl6DegAHIgCMQiYNGB5CJTdBz5ieADclta2wMzw2thEwATM2Pwe-t68vp4BuIKmoba2BIyIEAB0SV6kwu7p3sEWuYYhtbaoANa4AMrMRLRC2VaNNvV9uf5C5v250AD0k9AsrNBx0C24CwUwrPHNMHoLkna4Crp2BDkT%20YUlVXhFc5w8BEKng4OWoJAwJMAF8L25NIRgVISSQ1XLhSI6GJxBL-AiA6DArJjCZ5NZFWFgaAVDGg2wvcYOZyueSKZRqDSpKJ6fRY6AAIi4Xz0zEQNHwdNOt24hB69GeDTeUHk%20AQKDQ6AkYpAZEo1Dopi59wEInEUhkCiU8FU6k0VIMxhlVFoMFFqAwkrNJmRtgtaCBSDNuJsp3BUSh8X4tpA9qlgmtKIgRH2CS9glOuXOxS9tK94ds0wW2Gk70Q%20h%200cWkbjNgTAHlHAArXCxIoptP8SNyUMNFE5mZzBbMJZgVqrQrQDbYLbQHYEPYHDyIY7ZttRh1oG5sO48wROiau5ggXBFEDMfQVtFeooask62dPSz4pcEaAAM0Q2G0bRF4%20lFS180%203349HgOtSAHIn3oAIwfuQQIgABePgfj%20ACswDIP%20Ha4KmjAEJ%20ABMAAMKH6B%20hj7hYx4IreP60g%20wpgKa4rfvAoj8Oel4ENeJG3thQA)

but the better structure to handle it is to use different classes for each animal and no need to use animal

use can see it here ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrABASQIKXALbIA2A3qBpZUQNawDKA9gK6QAmAXABQCUAvAD5kkAJ4AaClQyxk0bvyGjQAX1AQYCFOmz0ZeQiWkAPOOwDO2fUTKSMZgO6F5g0qpBu1IVMWRmLVw3IwYKkAB2YAI2JwVDtUcFhIWAA5ZAJYAEIOO2h4KABzTylURkgzXOZUaEZ4LjN4xJS02A5yvMh8niCpKWgAC3AzADp6hKTU9Iw%20OLGm9NsMDxApWgYWdl4MIIWlqRloXm3lqjcl0G9fC11kAOJjUzZ-fGsthYWSsoqqmrqG8ebWrkCl0FlIzMxQghfrMJrAeDsipQHFBDu9SmZGMRYENiIx8lwAOSIHyhUIFDD9WDgeAYRBQCw1DCsNjMHzQcmhZDwaAYRiICl9TARRhsEQE%20HHRZvYJnLw%20PwYAAimNCA0g90Sjww11u3SokGaWRy7XyAG4FmZwAAvTLZNoFc2SjD2Kn5PrQI32jqO4ror7VWqkA3pMSWm1iF3gN3QUN-OawZTZYQiHivJ1giFQ0aNWESnpUfqDIbBzDTEs%20-MCoth0t2a2wCv5wvDSPRqbO13uxtSkJUfabPX5j4YrE4vFcABEOGIdzYKrVFj6yAAbpg4LB%20hgIsweZSRBg55ACTzUIL7AKqTTEIwRWIL-uAFbMcp3-LwZARO8RcBwDDCNh2PYJC4vYGQYDgRBWqUGB5KuNJzsQqr0n%208CYDQkCMPY6rVNIsgYAQNRrku6oACwAAwHuAiCIAgiQ8mYkINAy-KIKhZh9EBcBXoMfR-uw95-sQGK4TyrGwOxnEIBgqDwM%200BoDIZRDNqZKQEk8Hzsh%20y0jxd4PrAM4iHS7F8QBNB5DOQwTnmJyIhgtjIgQqJOsOmLYri%20IEsqiELvhjCrlu%205cqe5KUtSW5oDQFj-n5y6hYK4XEswdAWHB7KoMB%204QqZB6YdhjAYPkjTvr%20BHpDAzAEBgUAXs6shSTFoTwIwkJ3JSBBmAZq4WNe8BAfAbDirYSyyhcCoACpRlJsAmJqTwGDYTollkXqFL2lDDv6PxBs0sYws0ibJiC6ZUOCkK1Nm-zpDZTYDMMJbtiWCLrSJzmVtJ6JuWOnnjYK%204ZTu4AsGYxD7uUJA0Be4VNbA%206sYwVWUjBMg0jVshwAQoS7gVRU8r40m4p1f4WKEjB%20OAURrgVYU0qw4IMbAVQcqhIjKb9iQCejsCY9jFLIHQuVYVDNIw-ujibsgGCky6SCsluP5U7VSSoJD-4APS8jS-TNbIQ1OqcniGyAWKidS5Q6s8hhlrA57eUhkBcDt6TZASCH2wSd41i7ABMQwAKwAByoAQHsdlG7ouwA7AAnDQ%20Qe5d8YcASDFQOpuU%20VABLKDwjp0vA5t6JbxAjI4TkSqAJsUlNNLW%20ek1FYGJbJ%20yjcJ3GsLJ-QzLINnEqtwgQz9hXwRAA))

Comment: Actually there are many difference property for animal. Like maybe tiger has property stripe color, eye color and so on. Like we include bird, mammal, insect etc..
If possible, I don't wanna declare the property and methods manually on the parent class

Comment: that's right, you must not do it, instead, you need to create a new class that extends animal class

Comment: let me edit your code a little

Comment: I updated my answer, please let me know if it's what you want

Comment: Not really what I want. Actually the urchin class has a subset of data or collection of data and animal class supposed to have method like generate info, or create summary of the data. Or even filter the data. but to get the data this urchin / bottom class has the specific way to get the data. Example tiger has specific way to get it data but they must have the method like ```tiger.listAnimal()``` that will be called in animal

Comment: This answer looks correct for the question as asked; if the OP has a different question, they should consider editing the code in the question to include unsatisfied use cases.